# ggplot geom_text label x position is disoriented

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot is as below

[Bar Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEu13.png)

I am trying to align the labels on the bars. Y co-ordinate of the label position seems to be fine as I had mentioned the height of the bar as y position. However, for the x-cooridnate, I didnt specify a value, which is misplacing the labels as seen in the diagram.

My plot statement is as below:

```
p1<-ggplot(new_melt,
             aes(x=DRV_DAY_OF_WEEK,y=VALUE,fill=VAR)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")  +
  geom_text(aes(label = BAR_COUNT, y=GROUP_VALUE, vjust = -1), size = 4) + 
 theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_text(size=12),legend.position = "right",legend.title=element_blank()) + ylab("Events") + 
 scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("PERCENTAGE", "COUNT"),
                         labels=c("Percentage", "Count"))
```

Any idea on how to get the labels aligned with the bars?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved by adding position=position_dodged(width=1) to geom_text

```
geom_text(aes(label = BAR_COUNT, y=GROUP_VALUE, vjust = -1), position=position_dodge(width=1), size = 4)
```